# Passenger displays directory index instead of Rails web app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, apache, passenger

I have read many similar posts reporting this issue, but the root cause doesn't seem to be the same. When I open my web app in a browser, all I see is the list of files in the public folder displayed as a list and do not see my web app.

I have a web app that I am deploying to Ubuntu 11.0.4 server using Rails 3.0.11 and mysql2-0.2.7. I have a single virtual host set up in Apache.

```
<VirtualHost 172.220.104.194:80>
      ServerName eden.example.com
      DocumentRoot /home/scervera/www/dashboard/public
      <Directory /home/scervera/www/dashboard/public>

         AllowOverride all
        #Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have installed Passenger and configured apache2.conf file adding the following lines (copied and pasted from the passenger-install-apache2-module script:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby1.8
```

My permissions on /home//www/dashboard/ are set to root is owner and  as group.

Apache starts with no errors. There is a production.log and a development.log, but shouldn't there be a passenger.log too?

I'm a bit stymied over this and would appreciate some help. Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I ran: 
    $ sudo passenger-status

I got the following:

```
----------- General information -----------
max      = 6
count    = 0
active   = 0
inactive = 0
Waiting on global queue: 0

----------- Application groups -----------
```

So this seems to show that Passenger is running, but there are no domains shown in the Application groups section. That doesn't seem right. I can't find any articles explaining my specific issue on any site.

Comment: UPDATE: 02-12-2012 I am able to get the web app to work with passenger in standalone mode

Comment: Can you please throw some light how you were able to do it , i am having the exact same problem :(